# need help understanding this line of code

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am conducting 300 repeated random sampling of a sample size of 50 (14+20+16) from the following normally distributed sub population:

```
sub_pop = [14, 20, 16]
mean_list = [100, 200, 300]
std_list = [40, 70, 80]
```

my objective is to visualize the sampling distribution of the sample median of this sample by means of 300 repeated random sampling.

this is what I've done:

```
groups = [{'label': 'sub_one', 'mean': 100, 'std_dev': 40, 'size': 14}, 
          {'label': 'sub_two', 'mean': 200, 'std_dev': 70, 'size': 20},
          {'label': 'sub_three', 'mean': 300, 'std_dev': 80, 'size': 16}]

def median(mean, std_dev):
    data = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev) # indented function
    get_median = np.median(data)
    return get_median

group_all = []

for i in range(300):
    for i in range(groups[0]['size']):
        group_all.append(median(groups[0]['mean'], groups[0]['std_dev']))

for i in range(groups[1]['size']):
    group_all.append(median(groups[1]['mean'], groups[1]['std_dev']))

for i in range(groups[2]['size']):
    group_all.append(median(groups[2]['mean'], groups[2]['std_dev']))

sample = [abs(x) for x in group_all]
sns.distplot(sample, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

my doubt is... i do not quite get the first 4 lines of code. does python recognize that I want to randomly draw 300 samples from each of the 3 normally distributed sub population and that each of the sub population is normally distributed with its own respective mean and standard deviation?
much thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the first 3 lines of code - the `groups = [ ... ]`  part?

Comment: Please make clear your question.Also your code has indent problem, second and third "for"s should be under first "for".

Comment: Also - there's a bug in line #2 near the `sub_two`.  The string is opened with a single quote, but closed with a double-quote.  You need to use one or the other.

Comment: nope. its more of the part on the for loops! I'm unsure if by coding it this way, python understands that I want to to generate random samples by means of 300 repeated random sampling from each of  the normally distributed sub population and then add all samples from all 3 sub_pop in a list and then visualise the sampling distribution. t

Comment: am pretty new to python so don't mind my use of non technical terms

Answer (score 2):

The function itself and your group creation is correct but there's some small errors and things that could be better done.

You can do as you've done and iterate the median function over the group size. But the np.random.normal function can take a third parameter that is exactly this. So the function could be rewritten

```
def median(mean, std_dev, size):
    data = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev, size)
    get_median = np.median(data)
return get_median
```

The loops are a bit problematic. You iterate 300 times, equal to your 300 wanted simulations, but then each individual gets added to the group_all. Not the median of each population like I think you wanted. This is fixed in the above function using the size parameter.

Then there's two nestled loops that have the same variable name. In this case it does work but it's bad practice. The first for loop variable isn't used so it could better be called _. Also the two other loops are outside the first for loop and won't be iterated over. The loops could be changed to

```
groups_data = [[] for _ in range(3)]
for _ in range(300):
    for i, group in enumerate(groups):
        groups_data[i].append(median(group['mean'], group['std_dev'], group['size']))
```

You can also plot multiple groups in the same plot. Just stack them before the plt.show() call.

```
for group in groups_data:
    sns.distplot(group)
plt.show()
```

I think this code is cleaner and hopefully closer to what you wanted to achieve. Good luck!

Comment: hi sorry if the question wasn't clear, am not too sure on the technicalities of python as I'm pretty new to the program. my objective is to generate random samples from the 3 normal distributions and this is done by means of repeated random sampling of 300. then i add it into a list in order to visualise the sampling distribution.

Comment: i.e. I have a total population of 50 of which it contains 3 sub_pop each normally distributed differently. so wad I want to do is generate random samples from each of these 3 sub_pop and then add the results into the list "group_all"

Comment: and also because I'm conducting repeated random sampling of 300, I do it 300 times for each sub_pop.

Comment: Hi, no problems! As I tried to explain there was some problems with your code but the basic ideas was correct. Did you try running your code and mine? As far as I can understand this is what you want. Was the output still not as you expected? Perhaps you can draw an image or explain in what way the result isn't what you want it to be.